# Getting list data from SharePoint 2010 site using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get list data from sharepoint site using JQuery, but have got nothing returned yet, no errors in firebug either. Any clue what is wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Action Items</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://my_site/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        console.log("aaaa");
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
    });
}
```

Comment: can you see the request in firebug net tab? if so does it return a 200 status? Is this page on the same domain as sp?

Answer (score 4):

Right after your line

```
function processResult(xData, status) {
```

add an alert like this:

```
alert(xData.responseText);
```

That will show you what is coming back from the call to GetListItems.

also, you should change this line:

```
 $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").
```

to this:

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']")
```

which is more reliable across browsers. (See my blog post: http://sympmarc.com/2009/11/08/sharepoints-web-services-jquery-and-the-zrow-namespace-in-safari-and-chrome/)

As Rob Windsor mentions in his answer, I've got many of the SharePoint Web Services wrapped with jQuery to make them easier to use in my [SPServices jQuery library](http://spservices.codeplex.com). I'd suggest you try it out, as you won't have to do as much work.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest that you use the client object model instead of the Web services. Much richer functionality and much, much easier to use.

[The Client Object Model and jQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701783.aspx#Y2000)

If you really want to use the Web services, then I suggest you check out the [SPServices project](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Much, much easier? Well, I'm not sure about that. It all depends on what you know and what you're trying to do. I find the converse to be true. We don't have any context on what the task is above, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the ajax `success` event, not the complete event. The complete event doesn't have that signature.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

complete(jqXHR, textStatus)

success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a same-origin policy violation.

Check that the current url where runs the script, begins with `http://my_site/`

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Put the `processResult` function within `$(documnet).ready` and check